# Is there a way to embed a RFID scanner in a iOs App, built with react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, nfc, rfid

I'm currently developing an app with react native. I would like to be able to scan RFID tags with that app. I've read that it's not possible for iOs, but the posts are quite old so maybe this has changed? Or does anybody know workarounds? Maybe with iphone cases that have an integrated scanner?

Answer (score 0):

No.. RFID capabilities are not yet supported in iphones.. As an alternative, see if NFC can be of use to you as they are currently supported.. Please refer to this post

https://medium.com/@griffinmacias/understanding-rfid-nfc-and-ios-11-3b305fff24e6